# Planck's theory of heat radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, acoustics, thermal-radiation, dispersion

In his book [The Theory of Heat Radiation](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Theory_of_Heat_Radiation/UnGPVwLybcEC?hl=en) Max Planck says:

> 18. Since in nature $K_\nu$ can never be infinitely large, $K$ will not have a finite value unless $K_\nu$ differs from zero over a finite range of frequencies. Hence there exists in nature no absolutely homogeneous or monochromatic radiation of light or heat. A finite amount of radiation contains always a finite although possibly very narrow range of the spectrum. This implies a fundamental difference from the corresponding phenomena of acoustics, where a finite intensity of sound may correspond to a single definite frequency. This difference is, among other things, the cause of the fact that the second law of thermodynamics has an important bearing on light and heat rays, but not on sound waves. This will be further discussed later on.

Where $K_\nu$ and $K'_\nu$ are the intensities of the EM radiation at the frequency $\nu$ in the two planes of polarisation (for unpolarised light $K_\nu$ = $K'_\nu = K$). So for example he writes the total intensity as:

$$ K = \int_0^\infty d\nu (K_\nu + K_{\nu'}) $$

The confusing thing is that he contrasts light and sound saying *a finite intensity of sound may correspond to a single definite frequency* when this is not the case for light. Why is this so? Why wouldn't sound also have an intensity distribution like light?

Although Planck says *This will be further discussed later on* this does not appear to be the case. There are no other mentions of sound waves in the book.